# Copying a large number of files (>4GB) into a Kubernetes pod results in error code 137

Tags: kubernetes

I'm trying to find a workaround for this that isn't incredibly slow. I'm trying to download a large data folder from a Kubernetes pod for reupload to another cluster that is not connected to the outside internet. As stated, it's a very large folder, in excess of 4GB total.

Downloading via `kubectl cp` works, but when trying to reupload the pod runs out of memory. From my understanding of how kubectl cp works under the hood, the memory burden is on the receiving end, which needs to receive the entire tarball from stdin and hold it in memory before unpacking it, so that makes sense.

I'm trying to find a way to break up the folder contents into chunks in a way that is both fast and conserves memory. I can iterate through the entire folder and its subfolders and run a `kubectl cp` for each one, and it works, but it's incredibly slow and inefficient.

Comment: Pods are ephemeral and "lose files" when the containers restart. So, I assume that the 4GB directory is a mounted volume...Which type of volume are you using for this directory? Can't you copy files straight from the volume?